# What happens if we call two WLResourceRequests parallel in android native code.(IBM MobileFirst)

Tags: android, ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-adapters, mobilefirst-server

I am using WLResourceRequest  to call a server component in android .It works fine but I have question here what happens if I fire second service call while the first service call is still running.
**Will both run Parallel?**
I am using the following code to run WLResourceRequest.

```
WLResourceRequest request = new WLResourceRequest("Actual server path here", GET);
  request.addHeader(new BasicHeader("IfAnyHeader", "here"));
request.send(new ResponseListener());
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, both can run parallel, no problem.
In case your resources are protected you will get the challenges one by one.